# How to get JSON data from my url and localhost website in Visual Studio Apache Cordova

Tags: json, apache, visual-studio, visual-studio-cordova

How to get JSON data from my url and localhost website in Visual Studio Apache Cordova? I tried to debug it and choose local and it works fine, it display the result but when i release it and installed it ony my mobile phone nothing display.

here's the link where I want to gtet the JSON DATA
   http://pcbsonline.comeze.com/
and also from my localhost http://192.168.1.105/macbeth

Comment: Could you post a basic demo project that can reproduce your problem at your convenience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have not whitelisted your url's.  Look up Content Security Policy and whitelisting in PhoneGap docs.  This link is also helpful: https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/whitelist-matrix.md